# How to use MICE in Python for Categorical and Continuous data?

Tags: python-3.x, numeric, categorical-data, imputation, r-mice

I have a loan default data set which has both categorical and continuous features. Many features have missing values which I want to impute using MICE. I am not sure if MICE is even able to handle categorical data. [Screenshot of dataset,some columns are not visible here but you can get an idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfT90.jpg)
If someone can guide me here about how to use MICE or any other imputation method it will be very helpful.